# From Calendar to GregorianCalendar without cast

Tags: java

I'd like to get a `GregorianCalendar` object from an `instanceof` a `Calendar`. Obviously I could just cast the `Calendar` object because in most cases the real implementation of an abstract `Calendar` is the `GregorianCalendar`. But if I don't know what is the real implementation and I'd like to force the creation of a `GregorianCalendar` version of that other `Calendar`? How can I do?

I looked for many search engines but i found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it as GregorianCalendar extends Calendar.
I believe the only way is to cast it but checking instance of before:

```
if (cal instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
    GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = (GregorianCalendar) cal;
    ...
}
```

Comment: And if it isn't? I don't know how to handle the else statement, the then statement I already knew it is just a cast. Njol said that I should set something after the construction but I don't know if setTime and setTimeZone is enough.

Comment: I do not think it is all. Look at the Calendar code. It has a lot of fields like `minimalDaysInFirstWeek`, `firstDayOfWeek`, `sharedZone`, `zone` and `time`. I believe that you should consider setting all of them by revising the docs.

Answer (score -1):

simple:

```
new GregorianCalendar()
```

If you already have a calendar instance that you want to copy you should add the appropriate arguments from your existing calendar (e.g. the time zone) and/or `set()` them after construction (e.g. the date).

Comment: As I replied to Pisek, is enough just calling setTime and setTimeZone?

Comment: @user2714602 Calendar.getInstance() sets the time zone, locale, an the timestamp of the newly created calendar. So if you do not modify anything else, setting only those values should be fine.

Comment: here is a more concrete code snippet:
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
final GregorianCalendar gregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(cal.getTimeZone());
gregorianCal.setTime(cal.getTime());